# Переполняется массив

Tags: c#, winforms

https://github.com/Nikolinc/Simplex-
Делаем практику по создании программы для симплексного метода.
Постоянно переполняется массив. Преподаватель тоже не знает.
Благодарю за помощь.

Сам код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[,] table = new int[4, 6];
    float[,] sim = new float[4, 6];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        app();
        Simp();
        //textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(sim[1, 6]);
    }

    private void app()
    {
        table[1, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text);
        table[2, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        table[3, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);

        table[4, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
        // в этой строке происходит переполнение массива
    
        table[1, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        table[2, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        table[3, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        table[4, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
    
        table[1, 3] = 0;
        table[2, 3] = 1;
        table[3, 3] = 0;
        table[4, 3] = 0;
    
        table[1, 4] = 0;
        table[2, 4] = 0;
        table[3, 4] = 1;
        table[4, 4] = 0;
    
        table[1, 5] = 0;
        table[2, 5] = 0;
        table[3, 5] = 0;
        table[4, 5] = 1;
    
        table[1, 6] = 0;
        table[2, 6] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        table[3, 6] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
        table[4, 6] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас проблемы с кодом, приведите код, расскажите о задаче, что он решает, о проблеме в коде и тд. Ссылки на код здесь не нужны никому.

Comment: У вас ссылка не работает

Comment: Извиняюсь, так как пишу здесь первый раз

Comment: Убрал голос за закрытие

Comment: Не стесняйтесь искать и читать. Вбиваем в поиск "C# массивы" и получаем 2 первые ссылки [1](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) - _Массивы индексируются от нуля: массив с `n` элементами индексируется от `0` до `n-1`_

Answer (score 2):

В C# как и во многих других языках программирования индексация идёт не с 1, а с 0. Поэтому когда вы объявляете массив размером 6, индексы доступа к его элементам будут не от 1 до 6, а от 0 до 5.
С многомерными массивами принцип тот же. В каждом измерении индексация идёт от 0. Для массива int[4, 6] максимальные индексы будут [3, 5].

Comment: Самое интересное, что "Преподаватель тоже не знает.")))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ага, я фшоке ))